# How to change default location of OpenCart file manager?

Tags: opencart

After upgrading a website from opencart 1.5 to 2.3 I can't see the old uploaded images in file manager. My files are in /images/data/... while the file manager loads on /images/catalog/ and doesn't let me access any files beyond this folder. Is there a way to change the default location for file manager?

Luckily the older products still have the right links to their images, but since any new will have to be stored under /catalog directory, I will not be able to upload any new ones to already well made file structure.

Answer (score 0):

`admin/config.php` will give you the directory of your image files, you can also change it to point at the correct location.

Comment: the DIR_IMAGE does point to /images file, but nothing in the config seems to lock the file manager to /images/catalog... How do I change that?

Comment: admin/controller/common/file_manager.php is what you would want to edit if you want to specify a different location for your file manager.